# incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [10]' in C

Tags: c

**i want to assign the pointers on the first element of each array but i get this message -->incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'int [10]' in C **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ten 10
int main ()
{
  int min = 0, max = 0, *minptr, *maxptr, i;
  int arr1[ten], arr2[ten], *arr1_ptr[ten], *arr2_ptr[ten];
  arr1_ptr = &arr1[0];
  arr2_ptr = &arr2[0];
  minptr = &min;
  maxptr = &max;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The types are different. Type of `&arr1[0]` is `int*` but that of `arr1_ptr` is `int*[10]`. That's why this error message. You even copied the error message wrong.

Also note that maybe this is what you wanted

```
arr1_ptr[0] = &arr1[0];
```

Because now the types match and also it means - you are assigning a `int` variables address to the first element of an array where each element of the array is of type `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

`arr1[0]` is a *single* `int` value. Therefore `&arr1[0]` is a pointer to that single `int`. And therefore `&arr1[0]` has to be of type `int *`.

The variable `arr1_ptr` is an array of `10` pointers to `int`. If you want to make an element of that array point to an element of `arr1`, then you have to assign the address of an element of `arr1` to an element of `arr1_ptr`:

```
arr1_ptr[0] = &arr1[0];
```

If on the other hand you want a pointer to an array, then you have to do e.g.

```
int (*arr1_ptr)[ten] = &arr1;
```